# Why my angularjs service reloads each time I load a new page?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to save a season token in a service, but each time I load a new page it seems that the server resets itself

angular.service.js:

```
var appBooking = angular.module('Booking');
appBooking.service('WebService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {

    this.setToken=function (tkn){
        $rootScope.token=tkn;
    };

    this.getToken=function () {
        return($rootScope.token);
    };

    this.login = function (user, password) {
        var dato={'usuario':{'username': user, 'password': password}};
        return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/Booking/login',dato);
};
}]);
```

angular_apps.js:

```
angular.module('Booking', []);
```

angular_controllers.js:

```
var appBooking = angular.module('Booking');

appBooking.controller('CtrlLogin', ['$scope', 'WebService', function ($scope, WebService) {
    var self = this;


self.login = function (user, password) {
    WebService.login(user, password)
        .then(function (jsonObject) {
            console.log("Login success");
            location = "profilepage.html";
            token = jsonObject.data.token;
            WebService.setToken(token);
        }, function errorCallBack(response){
            console.log("Login failed");
        });
};
}]);
```

The controller LoginController is attached to a login form and it sets the value correctly, but when I load a new page $rootScope.token is undefined.

Inside the html pages I load a controller defined in the same document as  LoginController, for example:

```
appBooking.controller('CtrlProfile', ['$scope', 'WebService', function ($scope, WebService) {
//content here
}]);
```

and before every  tag in each html file I load the following scripts

```
<script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular_apps.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular_services.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular_controllers.js"></script>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the $window like this: `$window.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');` and retrieve the value like `this:$window.sessionStorage.getItem('key');`

Comment: From your description I suppose that you intend to use $rootScope.token before you initialize it. Try to define an onload function and use $rootScope.token inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Fo AngularJS not to reload your service, you need to make sure that AngularJS is handling all necessary in-app routes.  How are you handling in-page route changing?  For your code:

var appBooking = angular.module('Booking');

```
appBooking.controller('CtrlLogin', ['$scope', 'WebService', function ($scope, WebService) {
    var self = this;


self.login = function (user, password) {
    WebService.login(user, password)
        .then(function (jsonObject) {
            console.log("Login success");
            // What is this line supposed to do????
            location = "profilepage.html";
            token = jsonObject.data.token;
            WebService.setToken(token);
        }, function errorCallBack(response){
            console.log("Login failed");
        });
};
}]);
```

You have an assignment of `location`.  If that is being used to change the browser location, and that browser location change is not handled by the Angular JS app, then the browser page will reload, and your Angular JS app will reset.